# Converting Numpy Array to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have numpy array:

```
data = ['R' 'R' 'R' ... 'R' 'R' 'R']

#>>data.shape
(31728,)

#>>type(data)
numpy.ndarray
```

What do i need to do to change the array to a  pandas dataframe?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Start by reading some of the pandas documentation.  `df = pd.Dataframe(....)` is usually where pandas users start.  Look at some of the other questions tagged with `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only have a single dimension array, which will convert into a single column array (plus the index column).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = ['R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```